# Delay in CSS loading Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a webapp using Nuxt.js + Vuetify, after deploy this on Google App Engine I noticed a delay with CSS in some elements, like this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TkXk.gif)

How can I avoid this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `v-cloak` directive to hide your app (or other) element until the child image is loaded.

https://medium.com/vuejs-tips/v-cloak-45a05da28dc4
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Answer (score 0):

Hi Matheus and welcome to SO.

Does that data comes from an API ? If so, it's probably non-asynchronous so it's being executed after everything else finishes.
Can you show more code?